# What does "response too long" means in MongoDB Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

Sometimes I get this exception from MongoDB Java driver 2.10.1:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: response too long: 1912733750
  at com.mongodb.Response.<init>(Response.java:47)
  at com.mongodb.DBPort.go(DBPort.java:124)
  at com.mongodb.DBPort.call(DBPort.java:74)
  at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.innerCall(DBTCPConnector.java:286)
  at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.call(DBTCPConnector.java:257)
  at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:310)
  at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.__find(DBApiLayer.java:295)
  at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:368)
  at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:459)
  at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:484)
```

Obviously, my response is not that long. Actually it's rather small, there are just 1000 items in the collection, 100-500 bytes each. Why this may happen?

Comment: Possibly related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917943/why-do-i-end-up-with-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-for-casbah-java-mongod?rq=1

Comment: Upgrade of MongoDB java driver to version 2.11.2 does **NOT** fix the problem

Comment: Do you have multiple threads using the same cursor?

Comment: The error states that your response is almost 2GB in size, if I am not mistaken. Do you mind to show us the actual query? I assume it is an aggregation you are running?

Answer (score -1):

As the error description says, it is caused by a server which took too long to respond to the request. Possibly this is caused by firewall settings in your server. Try to check if the server can write response out through the port you are using for your MongoDB.